# Showing Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S = \{(x,y,z)\in R^3 : 2x-3y+5z=0\}.$ show that S is a real vector space using the  standard operations on $R^3$

Having trouble showing S is closed under vector addition because of the condition. Can I say, Let $\vec{a} = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and let $\vec{b}=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and add the two vectors and show they are closed under vector addition.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what you should do!

Comment: The two vectors should be from the plane $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec{a} = (a_1,a_2,a_3), \vec{b}=(b_1,b_2,b_3) \in S$ then
$$2a_1-3a_2+5a_3 = 0$$
$$2b_1-3b_2+5b_3 = 0$$
So
$$2(a_1+b_1)-3(a_2+b_2)+5(a_3+b_3) = 2a_1-3a_2+5a_3 + 2b_1-3b_2+5b_3 = 0+0=0$$

Answer (score 0):

@Crostul gives a complete, direct answer. Here's  a solution that will prove useful once you've learned about linear maps.

Let $T:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ be the linear transformation defined by 
$$
T(x,y,z)=2\,x-3\,y+5\,z
$$
Then $S=\ker T$ and the result follows from the fact that the kernel of any linear map is a subspace of the domain of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it should be checked wether $S$ is closed under addition:$$\vec{a}\in S\wedge\vec{b}\in S\implies\vec{a}+\vec{b}\in S$$

See e.g. the answer of Crostul for that.

But next to that it should also be checked wether:$$\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\wedge\vec{a}\in S\implies\lambda.\vec{a}\in S$$

Note that e.g. that $T:=S\cap\mathbb Z^3\subset\mathbb R^3$ is closed under addition but does not satisfy the last condition (hence is not a vectorspace over $\mathbb R$).